# I am working on an exercise to create an 2D java array that displays every number as a table and has the averages for each row/column

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So i have to make this program and I was able to make the program display the array with the row averages but I am finding it difficult to also display the column averages. My problems are that: 1. I cannot figure out how to add the column value similar to how I did with the row values. 2. I am also having trouble displaying the average column values below the table. Can anybody help?

```
public class ColRowAvg
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      int avg = 0;
      int[][] arr = {{6,3,4,2}, {3,4,5,7}, {3,6,7,2}, {3, 5, 2, 7}};
      for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)//Cycles through rows
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)//Cycles through columns
         {
            System.out.printf("%5d", arr[row][col]);
            avg += arr[row][col];
         }
         System.out.printf(" |%2d", avg/arr.length);
         System.out.println(); //Makes a new row
         avg = 0;
      }
      System.out.println();
      for (int col = 0; col < arr.length; col++)//Cycles through rows
      {
         for (int row = 0; row < arr[col].length; row++)//Cycles through columns
         {
            System.out.printf("%5d", arr[row][col]);
            avg += arr[row][col];
         }
         System.out.printf(" |%2d", avg/arr.length);
         System.out.println(); //Makes a new row
         avg = 0;
      }      
   }
}
```

This is what I have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap row and col in nested for loop

Comment: But then how do i get the column averages to display under each column?

Comment: Use underscore or something alike and display below